# Building a lambda expression using concatenation

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

Let's say I have these two entities :

- *Document*, which contains a DateTime property (called **Date**).
- *Period*, which contains two DateTime properties (called **DateFrom** and **DateTo**) that represents a period of time.

Then, consider this expression, in which *d* represents a *Document* and *p* represents a *Period*, that is used to filter a *Document* collection to return only those who are part of a given *Period* :

```
d => d.Date >= p.DateFrom && d.Date <= p.DateTo
```

The problem is, **given a collection of Period entities**, how could I build a lambda expression which represents a concatenation of multiple expressions like the above expression, so it gives :

```
d => 
     (d.Date >= p1.DateFrom && d.Date <= p1.DateTo) 
  && (d.Date >= p2.DateFrom && d.Date <= p2.DateTo) 
  && (d.Date >= p3.DateFrom && d.Date <= p3.DateTo) 
  && ...
```

I want the result to be a **lambda expression** that I can further combine to other conditions before filtering my Document collection.

Comment: Would it not be easier to restrict the result set in stages, rather than all in one big && fest?
If you're using Linq, it will build them up anyway, until you request data back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var documentsInAllPeriods = documents.Where(d => periods.All(p => 
    d.Date >= p.DateFrom && d.Date <= p.DateTo));
```

(Note you can change `All` to `Any` if you want the documents in any period rather than the documents in *every* period.)

Comment: I have edited my question to be more precise about what I want to acheive. I want to be able to combine that Expression to another Predicate.

Comment: @JoanLeaven It seems you're not particularly familiar with the terminology that you're using, because this answer meets the exact criteria of your question.  FYI I would think that this would work for either an `IQueryable` or an `IEnumerable`.  Have you tried it and seen it not work for an `IQueryable`?

Comment: It's because I haven't found a way to make this work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469268/building-a-custom-predicate-to-act-as-a-filter-using-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @JoanLeaven So you tried this code and it didn't run properly?  If you just want someone to fix your other code then asking the same question again isn't appropriate, see [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: I really want to be able to build a lambda expression out of this. I want to be able to use the resulting lambda expression as a filter against other filters before calling Where on an ObjectSet.

Comment: @JoanLeaven Then pull the lambda out; I fail to see the problem with that.  `Expression<Func<Document, bool>> e = d=> ExpressionFromAnswer;`  What's the problem?  Note that if you simply want to apply additional filters there's no need to pull out the expression; just call `Where` multiple times with each filter you want to apply.  It's much easier.

Comment: I am not filtering in-memory collection. It has to be sent to linq-to-entities to build a SQL query.

Comment: @JoanLeaven I'm aware of that.  It in no way changes my comment.  You can apply multiple `Where` calls to a single query, even a dynamic number of `Where` calls.  I do it all the time.  It's much easier than trying to hack together a single predicate, when it can be done.

Comment: Well, this will make me go into a totally new direction. I will try to apply multiple Where calls to avoid dynamically building a single predicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the collection of period entities (periods) is available for the lambda expression:

```
(d) => 
{ 
   bool cond = false;
   foreach(Period p in periods)  
   {
      // check period
      // return earlier if condition not met
   }

   return cond;
}
```